WriteToClosedSessionException For LDAP Conneciton Pool Despite it Being Read-Only
We have a Java service that uses the Apache Directory library to talk to an OpenLDAP directory.  We have two services: one does do some writes to the LDAP server but the other service doesn't at all.  The one that does has separate connection pools: one for the read-only user and one for the read-write.
We've started seeing the following error quite a bit in our logs
2024-12-10 08:23:45.563 [NioProcessor-143413] WARN  org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection - null [MDC: {}]
org.apache.mina.core.write.WriteToClosedSessionException: null
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.clearWriteRequestQueue(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1192) ~[mina-core-2.2.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.removeNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1153) ~[mina-core-2.2.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.removeSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:864) ~[mina-core-2.2.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:694) ~[mina-core-2.2.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) ~[mina-core-2.2.3.jar!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]

This is even on the service that only has read-access to the LDAP.
This seems to have come recently.  We have recently upgraded to Linux 9 and therefore the version of OpenLDAP and Apache Directory. We are seeing this across several but not all environments post-upgrade.
The stack trace on this error doesn't come back to our code at all.  I think it might be something internal to org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnectionPool - checking if the connection is still valid, or recycling it, or similar.
My questions:

Am I right that this exception is internal to the connection pool?
Why is it happening now and only for some environments?  Any ideas how to investigate further?
What is meant by "Writing" in this context?  Is it writing to an LDAP record or is it just sending data (e.g. filter criteria when searching) to LDAP? (i.e. is it write to LDAP or write to the stream?)
If it is write to LDAP, why are we seeing this in a service that has no write privileges and never tries to write?

I guess the second question is the main one: I'm a bit stuck how to dig deeper, or if I need to.

Not an answer.  Please look into the source code.  Maybe you might notice something.
https://nightlies.apache.org/mina/mina/2.2.3/xref/org/apache/mina/core/polling/AbstractPollingIoProcessor.html
Also I think it might be related to your session idle time.  It is trying to close sessions (which are still OPEN) according to the stacktrace.  So perhaps an early termination of sessions? or something is still running..
